# What's the maximum number of Gateways you can power off 1 Pylon?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

Rotterdam was mentioning on the WCS NA stream that he could power 14 gates off 1 pylon, but that 15 "might" be possible.  Alas, I have no SC2 so I cannot see if he is right or wrong.

Comment: don't be an artosis

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image: 16]

16 seems to be the max. credits to [/r/starcraft](http://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/1ok9uv/16_gates_1_pylon_in_response_to_rotterdams/)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible for 15 to be powered off one pylon. Ignore that other green blob, it only has 14 :)

[image: 15 gateways powered by one pylon]

Comment: Seems like you mist a spot just left of the Pylon :(

Comment: This answers the question of can 15 gateways be powered off of one pylon, but the other answer is better for the title of the question.